# Remove extra space around QLabel

Tags: qt, qt4, qlabel

I tried stylesheets with

```
padding:0px, 
text-ident:0px; 
margin:0px; 
border: none;
```

And through code, changing the Size Policy to Expanding.

The layout inside the widget which has the label has

```
QHBoxLayout* lyt = new QHBoxLayout();
setLayout(lyt);
lyt->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

And setting contents margins to 0 in the parent widget too.

The only way i got to make it smaller was setting Fixed size to less of the size. But the text has the word wrap property on, so it can be bigger and i cannot control that.

What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the extra spacing, then you can try the following on your layout. It worked for me.

```
lyt->setMargin( 0 );
lyt->setSpacing( 0 );
```

If you want to reduce the size of a particular QLabel, then you can set:

```
QLabel *myLabel = new QLabel( this );
myLabel->setMaximumWidth( MAX_WIDTH );
```

Comment: setMargin doesn´t work, setSpacing and setContentsMargins to a recently set layout normally works, but surprisingly not here. The label continues to have margins around it. Over and under.

Answer (score 0):

I already found out what was happening. The margins and all the stuff was working.

[image]

The problem was related to the borders. The top and bottom borders are 5 px height. If you set a border height, no matter which margins or padding you have, it will be a barrier for the contents. I´ll create another post to see what happens here, if there is another way to fix this, and override the positions of the borders.

Thanks!